# Permission denied for imjournal: rename()

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, selinux

after disabling and enabling SELinux the Apache and MySQL cannot start, this error shows in messages.log:

```
imjournal: rename() failed for new path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state': Permission denied [v8.24.0-34.el7 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

## Debug:

### ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i:

```
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(06/17/2019 12:50:55.444:179) : 
proctitle=/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(06/17/2019 12:50:55.444:179) : arch=x86_64 
syscall=open success=no exit=EACCES(Permission denied) a0=0x55edf621f410 
a1=O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_CLOEXEC a2=0666 a3=0x7ffc3f67e060 items=0 
ppid=1 pid=3966 auid=unset uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root 
egid=root sgid=root fsgid=root tty=(none) ses=unset comm=httpd 
exe=/usr/sbin/httpd subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null) 
type=AVC msg=audit(06/17/2019 12:50:55.444:179) : avc:  denied  { append } 
for  pid=3966 comm=httpd name=error.log dev="vda1" ino=318782163 
scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 
tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

### sestatus:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

Comment: Could you please rerun your commands and then add the output of `ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i`, `sestatus`, and `journalctl -u rsyslog` to your question. Also, which CentOS version are you running?

I found https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3693211 as well, does this apply to you?

Comment: I updated my question @Edward

Comment: Thanks. I see an access denied error for the Apache error.log. Are you sure that file has the correct SELinux context set?

Comment: I set up apache step by step with https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7 article. Please look at Step 5 in this article @Edward

Comment: OK. Then I think something went wrong with applying the `sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/var/www/example.com/log(/.*)?"` and `sudo restorecon -R -v /var/www/example.com/log` steps because the file context of the `error.log` file isn't OK. Look at the the audit log: it states the `error.log` file has the `httpd_sys_content_t` context, but it should have the `httpd_log_t` context. Could you show us the directory structure in place and the file contexts (`ls -laZ`)?